# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context on SwiftUI when Text is used multiple times, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, macos-catalina

I am encountering the following error message:

Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

on the this line:

```
 Picker(selection: $contact.type, label: Text("Select Testing Type"))
```

Error was popping up the moment I've added more lines with Text. did any one have the same problem? how can it be solved?

I am working with Catalina and iOS11.

here the whole code snippet:

import Combine
import SwiftUI

```
class Contact: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject <Void, Never>()
    static let types = ["Functional", "Automation", "Manual", "Mobile App", "Performance", "Security", "E2E", "Integration"]
    static let services = ["HandsOn Testing", "Test Management", "Test Process Setup", "Training", "Test Leadership"]
    var type = 0 {didSet { update()}}
    var service = 0 {didSet { update()}}
    var name = "" {didSet { update()}}
    var company = "" {didSet { update()}}
    var city = "" {didSet { update()}}
    var email = "" {didSet { update()}}

    var isValid: Bool{
        if name.isEmpty || company.isEmpty || city.isEmpty || email.isEmpty {
            return false
        }
    }

    func update(){
        //add log
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contact = Contact()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $contact.type, label: Text("Select Testing Type"))
                    { ForEach(0..<Contact.types.count)
                    {Text(Contact.types[$0]).tag($0)
                        }}

                    Picker(selection: $contact.service, label: Text("Select Testing Service"))
                    {ForEach(0..<Contact.services.count)
                    {Text(Contact.services[$0]).tag($0)
                        }}
                }
                Section {
                    TextField($contact.name, placeholder:Text("Name"))
                    TextField($contact.company, placeholder:Text("Company"))
                    TextField($contact.city, placeholder:Text("City"))
                    TextField($contact.email, placeholder:Text("Email"))

                }

                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.sendForm()
                    }) {
                        Text("Send Form")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Contact us"))

            }

        }}
    func sendForm(){

    }}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that it's a know issue that Xcode might point at the wrong line, and display an irrelevant error, when you have a bug in your SwiftUI code

Comment: I think the issue is that you have multiple items in your navigation view. Please post the whole `ContentView` code and fix the formatting

Comment: ok thanks, I have added the whole code in the description.

Comment: @Andrew any idea after looking at what I have added? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you copy/pasted code as it is in your module, then I assume the issue is everywhere in

> ForEach(0..<**Contact**.types.count)

you use type name instead of variable name **contact**

Comment: well the types and services are for the first fields which contains an array with options. the rest of the fields such as  TextField($contact.name, placeholder:Text("Name")) I have added after and since then the error occurs.